# Cant assign material to stairs

Tags: texturing, materials

I cannot find a way to assign-view the material I chose for a predefined stair.

This is what I have
[image]

Comment: If you are using an image, the default texture coordinates are UV coordinates. So you would need to create a UV map. As an alternative you can use other kind of coordinates, like object or generated, but you would need to  add a texture coordinates node and plug it to the vector input of the image texture. To learn about texture coordinates watch: Watch Bartek Skorupa’s video on how to [Manipulate texture coordinates](https://youtu.be/kAUmLcXhUj0?t=264)